# Error:- bash: tart: command not found... Similar command is: 'tar'

Tags: linux, oracle, tar, su

I have used Oracle Linux7.7 OS and i had created user with name oracle, my question is that while i am trying to login using

```
$ su - oracle
```

After enter successful logged in but some warning occur

```
Last login: Thu Nov 28 16:40:36 IST 2019 on pts/0
bash: tart: command not found...
Similar command is: 'tar'
```

How to fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong command - hyphens should not be used.

Please use the following command to login with oracle username:

```
$ su oracle
```